# How can you get the delete confirmation button to show up on UITableViewCell if you tap the cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have implemented a UITableView to allow the standard delete button to show up on the far right of a cell when the user swips over it. I have a use case where I want to show this same delete button when a user taps on a cell.

I am able to handle the tap in the delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but I can not figure out how to show the delete button. I have found a lot of references on how to show the delete icon on the left of the cell, but not for the delete button that shows up when you normally swipe. Is there a way to do this, or do I need to create my own custom button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to do this. You could simulate touches making a swipe, but that'd involve using private APIs. You will have to manually create your own delete button.

Comment: This is to show the controls on the left and the reorder indicator on the right. I want the delete button from the right. From Apple docs: When you call this method with the value of editing set to YES, and the UITableViewCell object is configured to have controls, the cell shows an insertion (green plus) or deletion control (red minus) on the left side of each cell and a reordering control on the right side. This method is called on each visible cell when the setEditing:animated: method of UITableView is invoked. Calling this method with editing set to NO removes the controls from the cell.

Comment: Oh, right. I'm afraid there is no way to do this. You could simulate touches making a swipe, but that'd involve using private APIs. You will have to manually create your own delete button.